# How to get the lag size of a consumer group in redis stream?

Tags: redis

Suppose I have stream `mystream`, and a group `mygroup`, how do I get the length of unconsumed messages?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`XPENDING`](https://redis.io/commands/xpending) command?

Comment: @ItamarHaber yes, but that is the pending size not lag size

Comment: So perhaps I'm not following, apologies for my slowness - please explain length and lag size.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Lag size is the size of messages that the no consumer has processed

Comment: Added an answer. What is the use case for reading the "lag"?

Comment: The use case is for monitoring and alerting, and I could even stop the publisher when there are too many messages unconsumed.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that afaik.

It is possible to get the last message ID delivered in a group and in a stream with the [`XINFO GROUPS` and `XINFO STREAM`](https://redis.io/commands/xinfo) commands, respectively.

However, there is no command that returns the length of a stream subrange. Such command, was it to exist, would probably require linear time complexity and in that case, it will probably not be implemented.

Comment: I thought this would be some meta info that redis could update when new messages were published and consumed. I believe that there are such functionality in kafka

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`XINFO GROUPS`](https://redis.io/commands/xinfo-groups/)

The command `XINFO GROUPS mygroup` will provide a field in the response for lag.

According to the documentation:

> lag: the number of entries in the stream that are still waiting to be delivered to the group's consumers, or a NULL when that number can't be determined.

If you are wondering why lag can be null:

> There are two special cases in which this mechanism is unable to report the lag:
>
> - A consumer group is created or set with an arbitrary last delivered ID (the XGROUP CREATE and XGROUP SETID commands, respectively). An arbitrary ID is any ID that isn't the ID of the stream's first entry, its last entry or the zero ("0-0") ID.
> - One or more entries between the group's last-delivered-id and the stream's last-generated-id were deleted (with XDEL or a trimming operation).
>
> In both cases, the group's read counter is considered invalid, and the returned value is set to NULL to signal that the lag isn't currently available.

More details can be found at https://redis.io/commands/xinfo-groups/